# WLST - Node Manager Commands : "nmStart" can it start many weblogic servers at the same time?

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

we are using "WLST - Node Manager Commands" to control our servers restart.

but to minimize the restarting time, can we run multi servers at the same time ?

our code right now working like this :

```
nmConnect('weblogic','password','net4dns','5556','mydomain','/weblogic103/domains/mydomain')
    nmStart('Net4')
    nmDisconnect()
```

this code is starting Net4 server only but I want to start many servers together.

is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you use this following logic block='false' that allows you parallel processing

```
    connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://yourhost.com:7001')
    start('net1', block='false')
    start('net2', block='false')
    start('net3', block='false')
```

Comment: This requires the admin server to be up and while it's not bad advice per se I don't feel it answers the spirit of the original question which is whether nmStart can possibly launch servers concurrently.  To my knowledge it isn't possible.  One must resort to launching multiple scripts with separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
nmConnect('weblogic','password','net4dns','5556','mydomain','/weblogic103/domains/mydomain')
nmStart('Net4')
nmStart('Net5')
nmStart('Net6')
nmStart('Net7')
nmStart('Net8')
nmDisconnect()
```

Comment: it's cant work in that way, I have to connect to different servers also.

Comment: if your managed servers are on different physical hosts then you need to connect to the node manager on each physical host, then start the managed servers.  Hopefully you are not running only one managed server per machine, unless you have very small machines.